# Adding axis to a .png file

Tags: python, image, axis, mandelbrot

On a mission i took to myself i tries to make the Mandelbrot set, and my next step is to add axis to the image.
Since it's a picture and not a graph, this is very difficult.
Can you help me?
Thx

Comment: Like this? https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/event_handling/viewlims.html#sphx-glr-gallery-event-handling-viewlims-py

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of what you're trying to do? If you use `matplotlib.pyplot` to display the visualization you should get axes by default.

Comment: @MarkSetchell exactly, thank you.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project.

Comment: @jbencook I am not using  matplotlib, i was using a PIL module to help me jenerate an image.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/py-gnuplot/